# Error: Invariant Violation: Failed exporting HTML for URL contacts (src\pages\contacts.js): Browser history needs a DO M

Tags: reactjs

Got this error on every page when building the site:

> Error: Invariant Violation: Failed exporting HTML for URL contacts
>   (src\pages\contacts.js): Browser history needs a DOM

The site runs well in developer mode (using yarn start) and i can browse every page.